# View is loaded twice using angular ui router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am having a problem in my view. The view is loaded twice and I have no idea what's going on.
[image]

What I have done in my index file is this:

```
<body class="ng-cloak">
  <!--Menus-->    

  <div class="container-fluid">
      <div data-ng-controller="HomeCtrl" class="row">
           <!--Here is the ui view directive-->
          <div class="col col-md-12"  data-ui-view ></div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <!--script files here-->
</body>
```

On the routes file I have these. The problem only occurs when i visit the contact.inner page

```
$stateProvider
            .state('home', {
                url: '/',
                templateUrl: 'partials/home.html'
            })
            .state('contact', {
                url: '/contact',
                templateUrl: 'partials/contact.html'
            })
            .state('contact.inner', {
                url: '/inner',
                templateUrl: 'partials/inner.html'
            });
```

Comment: home.html should have partial contents. Do not add <html><head><body> tags inside home.html. Routers are getting partial templates and put it into main template (index.html)

Comment: No there are only partial contents other than the main index file

Comment: then, could you create plunkr for looking this issue

Comment: looks like I have figured out what went wrong. I had not created the `contact.html` page so this was creating the issue. Anyway Thanks